# Increase width of App bar button in WP8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, appbar

While using the Appbar button in the CommandBar of a Page, content of the Appbar button is fixed it seems. So that the width is not increase based on the Content.

Is there any work around to make visible the whole content or like wrapped content?

Thanks in advance.

```
<CommandBar BorderBrush="White"
            BorderThickness="1"
            IsSticky="True">
   <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="return to yard" />
   </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's funny but it depends on your phone's language. I have discovered it in my own app, where one of AppBar buttons has long label. When the language is set to Polish, then the label wraps and has two lines. But in English it has the same problem like you... One line and clipped (first button in screenshots below).

Polish: 
[image]

English: 
[image]

The answer to your question is: there is no way to change the size of AppBar buttons or labels. You have to come up with some shorter label...

Comment: Yeah, it's advisable to come up with a shorter label because it's aesthetically pleasing. But that can be hard some times.

Comment: Thanks for Your Suggestions.In this scenario i used same label language.Is there any work around to make visible the whole content or like wrapped content?let me know